# Blend 2012. How to Show Different Resoultions for Window 8 Phones?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, blend

Windows 8 phones now have 3 resolutions vs 1 resolution WP7 had. I am wondering when I am designing in Blend 2012 if it is possible to switch to these resolutions to see how things look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Device window (Window | Device), where you can set the resolution

[image]